# Logcat error message - Attempted to destroy barrier with non zero count

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, logcat

I'm making an android app in Android Studio, integrating ParseCloud and when I try to retrieve some **JSONObject** from the cloud, I get this error message after step-debugging:

```
12-13 13:32:34.857 25631-25638/com.parse.starter A/art: art/runtime/barrier.cc:90] Check failed: count_ == 0 (count_=-1, 0=0) Attempted to destroy barrier with non zero count
12-13 13:32:34.858 25631-25638/com.parse.starter A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366] Runtime aborting --- recursively, so no thread-specific detail!
12-13 13:32:34.863 25631-25638/com.parse.starter A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:366]
12-13 13:32:34.882 25631-25638/com.parse.starter A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 25638 (JDWP)
```

Problem arises in this piece of code in **ParseDecoder.java**, precisely on the `while` line:

```
Map<String, Object> convertJSONObjectToMap(JSONObject object) {
    Map<String, Object> outputMap = new HashMap<>();
    Iterator<String> it = object.keys();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      String key = it.next();
      Object value = object.opt(key);
      outputMap.put(key, decode(value));
    }
    return outputMap;
}
```

As I've seen while debugging, the object I wait for is created and is filled with one entry, but then this happens and I'm little bit lost... Any guidance will be great, thank you very much!

Comment: Hey! Error was on the call I made to the function; I had to write the call like it was an <Object> the returned object. It was working that way. 

ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("usersInDistanceOfGeoPoint", params, new FunctionCallback<Object>() {

            @Override
            public void done(Object object, com.parse.ParseException e) {

   .....

Comment: Are you using android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"?

Comment: can you also post the contents of `decode`?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem. I was using an old version of Parse library and it was interfering with the new one. I've just changed the `Parse.initialize()` lines to:

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
        .applicationId("MY_APP_ID")
        .clientKey("MY_CLIENT_KEY")
        .server("MY_SERVER_URL")
        .build()
);
```

and it worked!